# Can I use the same smartphone for two factor on 3 separate Gmail accounts?

Tags: gmail, multi-factor-auth

I have three separate Gmail accounts and I'd like to use two-factor authentication on all three.  Unfortunately, I do not have three cell phones on which to install the app.

Can I somehow use two-factor for three different account on the same cell phone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You surely can. The [Google Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2) app allows you to add as many accounts as you like!

As Dez mentions correctly, in addition to this, you can also use the same phone number for multiple text messaging authentication accounts.

Comment: Addition to this: You can also use the same phone number for multiple text messaging authentication accounts.